# How should time series data be grouped?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, churn

I'm fairly new to time series classification. I have an employee churn problem where I have quarterly data of the employees available.

Should I group my observations by time (example in table A) or by employee (example in table B)?

```
Table A
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|  Employee Nr  |   Timestamp   | Other_Features|    Churned    |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|       1       |      1        |      --       |       0       |
|       2       |      1        |      --       |       0       |
|       1       |      2        |      --       |       1       |
|       2       |      2        |      --       |       0       |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|


Table B
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|  Employee Nr  |   Timestamp   | Other_Features|    Churned    |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|       1       |      1        |      --       |       0       |
|       1       |      2        |      --       |       1       |
|       2       |      1        |      --       |       0       |
|       2       |      2        |      --       |       0       |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to be a Panel Data rather than a time series, because there are both timestamps and "spatial" stamps (individual). However as the name states, a time series should be ordered by time continuously, that is Table B. But as this is actually a Panel Data that choice might have other consequences, for example if you want to model Dynamic Panel Data, and you have plenty time observations.